# How can I distinguish a freeze frame from the moving parts of the video?

Tags: after-effects, presentation

Im wondering whats a good way for distinguishing (marking) a freeze frame from the moving parts of the video so it will not look like a problem that stopped the video player app?
I prefer keeping the freeze frame as clean as possible with minimal effects and markings.

Comment: Hi -can you explain what you’re looking for a bit more? Maybe with screenshots? It’s not clear to me.

Comment: I ended up adding flash to white effect like a camera flash as recommended here https://www.reddit.com/r/AfterEffects/comments/gvufem/how_to_distinguish_a_freeze_frame_from_the_moving/, by using “fade in-out frames” (in) effect on the first 5 frames.

Answer (score 0):

Add a sound effect: the effect fades in, is audible at full volume shortly before it abruptly ends exactly when the freeze frame appears. The sound effect should be distinguishable from background sounds and overall be crisp and short (like 0.5-2 seconds). That way, the audience is given a clear indicator that the freeze frame is intentional. An alternative might be a sudden tempo/rhythm change in music - but I wouldn't stop the music.

Comment: You might also include a link to [Sting (musical phrase) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(musical_phrase)).